# Hexadecimal to plain text conversion in c#

Tags: c#, hex

I need to convert a byte array into a readable plain text string. I had a look at this [How do you convert a byte array to a hexadecimal string, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) but it converts it to a hex string in ASCII. I am looking for a plain text string equivalent.

i.e when you make use of this website https://codebeautify.org/hex-string-converter , you should be able to post your hexidecimal text and get the converted string.

Take this Hex string for example: `47617465776179536572766572`, the plain text output is `GatewayServer` I want to achieve this in code.. my packet data is coming as a byte array.

Comment: This just takes the byte array and converts it into hex. I need the plain text string equivalent..

Answer (score 1):

Simple *Linq* seems to be enough: we extract ascii codes: `47`, `61`, `74`, ... `72` convert them into `char`s and finally `Concat` all these characters into `string`:

**Code:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Globalization;
  ...

  string source = "47617465776179536572766572";

  string result = string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, source.Length / 2)
    .Select(i => (char)int.Parse(source.Substring(2 * i, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber)));

  // Let's have a look
  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  GatewayServer
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

var encodedString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray);